# How to Control Time Expires of a 1 session in Classic ASP?

Tags: session, asp-classic, session-variables, session-cookies

I have 3 sessions -

1- USER
2- LANGUAGE
3- COUNTRY

When session expires - user is redirect to login and receive a message: "You are disconnected by inactivity"

Its ok. but..

**MY ISSUE:**

Because I lost session - I lost ALL 3 Sessions - and I don't know the LANGUAGE and COUNTRY of the user.

Then I Always print an English alert (default language)

What I want:

A way to control de timeout of each session. With this I can expires User Session first - and get the other two parameters to print the right language.

Is it possible?

I know how to expires - but ALL sessions..

tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookies, so you can control the time, even if the user closes the browser

```
Response.Cookies("name_cookie")("language") = 1
Response.Cookies("name_cookie")("country") = 1
Response.Cookies("name_cookie").Expires = now + 365
```